# Is this a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that makes $x^3 \le 8$ a.e. true

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So I'm looking for a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that makes $x^3 \le 8$ almost everywhere true.

$\Longleftrightarrow$ I want a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu \{x: x^3 > 8\} = 0$.

$\Longleftrightarrow \mu(2, \infty) = 0$.

Well if take the measure to be the dirac measure $d_0$ then I will have that as $0 \notin (2, \infty)$, then $\mu(2, \infty) = 0$

So $d_0$ is a measure that makes $x^3 \le 8$ almost everywhere true. Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: Yes. That's it.

Comment: Could I define a less trivial measure that makes it true like so - Let $f$ be $\chi_{(-1, 0)}$. I.e. an integrable simple function. Then $\tau(E) =  \int_{E} f dm$ defines a measure. And then when $E = (2, \infty)$ we have that $\tau(2, \infty) = 0$. Does that seem ok?

Comment: Yes. That's also good!

Comment: @sonicboom; Why not write your comment as an answer and accept it?